# Login to a host behind a gateway in Netbeans

Tags: ssh, eclipse, remote, gateway, netbeans

I want to work on a large project set up on a remote machine behind a gateway:
e.g:

First I login with username@abc.def.org 
This is the gateway and the actual machine I have my project is say,
               aaa.def.org

I was able to connect to abc but not to the next level. I've spent quite a time trying on eclipse and then Netbeans. Any suggesions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an easy way to do this with least messing up with installations on both windows and linux when you need to work on a remote linux system.
posted here:

http://umayanganie.blogspot.com/2017/05/build-debug-cc-projects-via-remote.html
Files you have  edit

Remote:

Your bashrc script or bash_profile - This  is hidden in /home/username
                                  Do : ll  -a  then vi  bash_profile
 Remote development by synchronized projects uses git. You need git installed on your remote machine. So we need to add the lines below to the end of your bash_profile script.

```
module load git
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m" 
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m"
git config --global pack.threads "1"
```

Local:

Eclipse supports Git inherently. So we only need to install eclipse  neon for parallel C/C++ development and follow the guide here(for detailed description) to set up connections

```
1- add connections (window>preferences>connections)
2- open connection
3- create a synchronized empty project
4- use same names for the local project as the remote project
5- right click on project and synchronize.
```